# Git - If we want to take a snapshot - should we Branch our should we Commit?

Tags: git-commit, git-branch

Let's say I'm working on this thing, and I want to preserve this state, so that, if something goes wrong, I can revert to it.

According to this, it's not clear to me:

What should we do when on this situation:

commit or create branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Git Tag is what you are looking for.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: So, commit and then tag. I believe we should avoid tag over usage because we may end up with "stables" that "really aren't" stables further on, or is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: Check this webpage http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html. You can them anything you want and later you can delete then too.